# Starting tmux with certain command inside of bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, arguments, tmux

I ran into problem when tried to start `tmux` inside of bash-script. 
The following script is sample of the problem.

```
tmux new-session -d -s main
tmux send-keys -t main 'ls ~/' C-m
tmux attach-session -d -t main
```

This script works correct - it started `tmux` with list of `~/` directory. 
Then I tried to start same command (`ls ~/`) as a variable

```
tmux new-session -d -s main
foo="'ls ~/'"
tmux send-keys -t main "$foo" C-m
tmux attach-session -d -t main
```

However, It didn't work. I have got the following message

```
'ls ~/'
$ 'ls ~/'
-bash: ls ~/: No such file or directory
```

What is the reason of this problem and how to fix it?

Comment: You can't stick quotes inside quotes and have the shell remove them for your correctly. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for a full discussion on this. Drop one set of the quotes there. Either `foo="ls ~/"` or `foo='ls ~/` but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stick quotes inside quotes and have the shell remove them for you correctly.

See mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for a full discussion on this.

Drop one set of the quotes there.

Either `foo="ls ~/"` or `foo='ls ~/'` but not both.